# MultipleThreading | Later thread overriding ThreadLocal values

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a program for multi thread processing where I am creating instances of thread in a `while` loop with each thread having a separate copy of their `local variables` as below:

```
while(cond.){
    ...
            //calling thread class constructor with local parameters
            ad = AddDoc.getInst(count, connection, userDetails, documentClass, uploadDoc, propMap, b, mimType, folderId, existingDocList, nonexistingDocList, errorDocList, mimType, bhamashahId);
            ad.start();
    ...
}
```

Above code creates a new thread for each document uploading operation.

Now I am making use of `ThreadLocal` for running multiple threads in my `Thread class` as below:

```
class AddDoc extends Thread {

    private ThreadLocal<Object> context = new ThreadLocal<Object>();

    ...
    some other variables
    ...
    Map<String, String> propMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

    private List<Object> list;

    public AddDoc(int count, CEConnection connection, String[] userDetails, String documentClass, boolean uploadDoc, Map<String, String> propMap1, byte[] b, String mimetype, String folderId, List<String> existingDocList, List<String> nonexistingDocList, List<String> errorDocList, String sessionUser, String bhamashahId) {

        list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(propMap1);
        list.add(connection);
        list.add(userDetails);
        list.add(documentClass);
        list.add(uploadDoc);
        list.add(b);
        list.add(mimetype);
        list.add(folderId);
        list.add(sessionUser);
        list.add(bhamashahId);

    }

    public Object getTransactionId() {
        return context.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        context.set(list);

        //calling getTransactionId() method and retrieving the stored List
        List<Object> runList = ( ArrayList<Object> )getTransactionId();

        //Retrieving Map stored in List
        Map<String,String> runMap = (Map<String,String>)runList.get(0);

        ..somewhere down a few line of codes..
        //printing Map values
        logger.info("Map in Thread > "+runMap);
}
}
```

**PROBLEM**:

While printing the Map in `run()` method I am getting the `Map` of the thread which is called later in the `while` block.

That means for 2 threads initialized, the second thread called later, `overrides` the `Map` stored in `ThreadLocal` which completely according to me violates the concept of `ThreadLocal`.

Am I using **ThreadLocal** wrongly? Please suggest.

Thank you

Comment: While you don't need `ThreadLocal` in this case at all, using it is not the cause of your problem. You may be facing a race condition or something. - You don't *modify* `propMap` in the while loop after you started the first thread, do you?

Comment: yes it is being modified. `propMap` will be different for each thread

Comment: Do you *modify* one single map or do you create a *new* map in each iteration?

Comment: Its single map only

Comment: Ok, that means that every thread gets the *same* instance of the map, so all threads see the same contents and all the changes you make to the map afterwards. Solution: Don't share mutable objects between threads unless you have to. Create a new Map for every thread. Either make a copy inside the thread's constructor or pass a new copy to every thread.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one instance of the `ThreadLocal` shared between threads.

You should either make it `private static final` field visible to all `Thread`instances or inject single `ThreadLocal` instance to all threads.

For the future reference, javadoc should provide enough information to use any of the Java API classes:

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
>   from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
>   (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized
>   copy of the variable. ThreadLocal instances are typically **private
>   static fields** in classes that wish to associate state with a thread
>   (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).

Comment: So the `ThreadLocal` instance should not be used in Thread class but the caller?

Comment: it can be used in  a Thread class if you make it shared between all instances of the Thread class. Such as with static field.

Comment: `ThreadLocals` should indeed be used in code that may run in different threads. A `Thread`s `run()` method will only ever run in that single thread.

Comment: @Jimmy I am accessing static `ThreadLocal` of my parent class in constructor of `Thread` class. But it still overrides